# What are these weeds? Should I bother rooting them out

Tags: identification, weeds

Are these plants worth growing? Or they are plain useless?

Weed 1

[image]

[image]

Weed 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you? You haven't even stated a continent, never mind somewhere more specific

Comment: bottom one looks a little like plantain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago#Species) just not the variety I have here.

Comment: @ChrisH In Delhi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom one is one of the plantains and not something you want in a pot, remove it before it drops its seed everywhere.

No. 1 looks like new shoots of a woody plant or shrub of some sort - is there something else growing there that's previously been cut back?

Comment: Yes, money plant.

Comment: CAn I grow plantain in another pot? Or it is useless?

Comment: It has uses, but grows better in the ground, info here on two types of plantain,  not sure which plantain you have there though https://www.gardenorganic.org.uk/weedy-wednesday-plantain